# Uncommon uses of the preposition 'with'

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases, prepositional-objects

It strikes me that the way we use 'with' is more complex than we may think. So I have two questions:

- Can the preposition 'with' be used to mean 'about' or 'in relation to'? (sentence a and b). 
  And also:
- Can the preposition 'with' be used as 'among' (sentence b)

> a) ... because in a moment, we need to get back to **my point with Eliot**
>
> b) He has become very popular **with the people**
>
> c) The world has not responded in ways similar to **what we have seen with
>   other** crises like the Hawaiian earthquake

These sentences are taken from public lectures 'with' well established writers and political commentators.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "sentences **"a" and "b"**" I gather you mean sentences **"a" and "c"**.

> "...because in a moment, we need to get back to my point with Eliot."
>
> "...similar to what we have seen with other crises like the Hawaiian earthquake."

Yes, it means "in relation to", "concerning", "regarding".

> "He has become very popular **with** the people."

here it means **"among"**, **"in the same group as"**.

> "At the beginning of his carreer, Bob Dylan was very popular with the College crowd."